# Checking for rising edge of simulated clock in testbench

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to do events on the rising edge of a clock in a test bench and the normal method is not working. What appears to happen is it cannot evaluate the statement so never progresses, which makes sense since it is trying to accomplish the rising edge check concurrently with the clock signal... I think...

Do I need to place the `do_stuff` process logic in a separate instantiation and feed the clock signal into it?

This example is stripped of all the actual UUT signals, actual test logic, and the component itself for brevity while still highlighting the base problem.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;

entity tb is
end tb;

architecture Behavioral of tb is

constant clk_period : time := 10 ns; -- 100 MHz clock
signal s_clk : std_logic := '0';
signal i : integer := 0;

begin

    ref_clk : process
    begin
        s_clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        s_clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
    end process ref_clk;

    do_stuff : process
    begin  
        if(rising_edge(s_clk)) then
            if(i < 20) then
                i <= i + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process do_stuff;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: @gsm you mean `wait until rising_edge(s_clk);` ;)

Comment: ... but anyhow. The code you wrote seems about right. You should add `s_clk` to the sensitivity list of the process. I.e. `do_stuff : process(s_clk)`.

Comment: Ha, indeed you are correct

Comment: That worked! Post it as a solution so I can mark it answered (and give you the points). Thanks!

Comment: Also FYI about the sensitivity list, `ERROR: [VRFC 10-1281] process cannot have both a wait statement and a sensitivity list`